# html-webpack-plugin: How to inject parameters like title into the template

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to pass title to html-webpack-plugin but it does not create title tag at all :(

Can somebody show me where is the problem

**webpack.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/app/main.ts'],
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: 'dist'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title : 'Hello',
            template: './src/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: loaders
    }
};
```

And here is **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript">
    </noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start webpack server title is not injected?

Answer (score 11):

Try this `<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>` in your html file. For reference you can check [index.html](https://github.com/samarpanda/webpack-setup/blob/webpack-2/src/index.html#L4) file in my repos [webpack-setup](https://github.com/samarpanda/webpack-setup/tree/webpack-2).

Comment: Can you explain how this works? There must be some kind of templating engine running somewhere at build time to process this.

Comment: @Andy It is basically the feature of webpack which internally uses tapable hooks. And all the plugins developed around webpack also leverages those hooks. Especially for html-webpack-plugin you can refer these events flow: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#events

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been reported here [Title not working. #176](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/176)

If you want to add the dynamic `<title>` tag, you should use a template language like `ejs`, `jade`, ...

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack insert this configuration

```
{
    test: /\.(index.html)$/,
    use: [
      {loader: "file-loader"},
      { loader: "extract-loader" },
      {
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        attrs: [':data-src']
      }
    }]
  }
```

Insure this configuration:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: "My Page TItle",
  template: './index.html'
}),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can now use templateParameters like so:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'index.html',
  templateParameters: {
    title: 'My web app',
  },
```

and in your index.html file header:

```
    <title><%= title %></title>
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried inject the title tag in template html file `./src/index.html`?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript">
    </noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```